# Symfony2 - Doctrine OneToMany Select-Issue

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I have two entities: One Account can manage several Customers.

**Account**

```
class Account {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Account", mappedBy="account", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $customers;
}
```

**Customer**

```
class Customer {
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Account", inversedBy="customers", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="accountid", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $account;

    # + other ManyToMany-Relations
}
```

Now I would like to select all accounts and print customer-data in my Twig template. So I use the following query:

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$customers = $qb->select('acc')
    ->from('AppBundle:Account', 'acc')
    ->leftJoin('AppBundle:Customer', 'customer', 'WITH', 'customer MEMBER OF acc.customers')
    ->where('customer.active = true')
    ->orderBy('acc.id', 'ASC')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

This works perfectly fine but when accessing the customer-data another query gets executed for each customer. That means that I have 101 executed queries when printing 100 customers. That's way too much. How can I combine this in one query so that the customer-data gets returned with the account data?

Comment: try $qb->getResult(Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);, this might prevent accidental lazy loading (seems like there is some lazy loading going on )

Comment: When using HYDRATE_ARRAY then I just get an array of the Account. There are no Customers included. How do I need to adjust my query?

Comment: You have a full example [here](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/djrc/full-webform-style-crud-example-with-an-embedded-associated-entity-in-symfony). Includes Entity, Repository, FormType, Twig.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the customers in select method could do the trick to minimize executed queries.

```
$customers = $qb->select('acc, customer')
    ->from('AppBundle:Account', 'acc')
    ->leftJoin('AppBundle:Customer', 'customer', 'WITH', 'customer MEMBER OF acc.customers')
    ....
;
```

Comment: That causes to return Accounts and Customers seperately (array(20) { # Account } array(4) { #Customer } array(20) { #Customer } array(4) { #Account } ...} - I need the Customers in the Account arrays. Otherwise I can't iterate over the result in my Twig template.

Comment: Have you confirmed the query is reduced? How is your twig access the result?

Comment: In my twig template I would have a {% for customer in accounts.customers %}.

Comment: Update your question so I can update my answer according to it.

Answer (score 0):

So, this is feature of Doctrine2. All relations lazy loads, if you want access to it.

As solution, you can [change fetch mode](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#temporarily-change-fetch-mode-in-dql) before execute query.

Comment: Is there a way to check whether or not the correct fetch mode is used? I tried to enable it but there is no difference.